# typeORM blacklisted user

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

In my social application, users may wanna blacklist a user (like lots of social application).

#### I have 2 entities:

**User** *(but blacklisted user)* ManyToOne **Blacklist**

**User** ManyToMany **Blacklist**

User:

```
@Entity()
@Unique(["username"])
export class User 
{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
@Length(4, 20)
username: string;

@Column()
@Length(4, 100)
password: string;

@Column()
@IsNotEmpty()
role: string;

@Column()
@CreateDateColumn()
createdAt: Date;

@OneToMany(type => Blacklist, blacklist => blacklist.user)
blacklist: Blacklist[];

@ManyToMany(type => Blacklist)
@JoinTable({
  "name": "user_blacklist"
})
blacklists:Blacklist[]

@Column()
@UpdateDateColumn()
updatedAt: Date;

hashPassword() {
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password);
}

checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid(unencryptedPassword: string) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(unencryptedPassword, this.password);
}
}
```

Blacklist:

```
@Entity()
export class Blacklist {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.blacklist)
  user: User;
}
```

This is the method I'm calling on **post('user/blacklist')**

```
static addBlacklist = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { id, blacklisted_id } = req.body;

  const blacklistRepository = getRepository(Blacklist);
  const userRepository = getRepository(User);

  let user: User
  let blacklistedUser: User;
  try {
    user = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
    blacklistedUser = await userRepository.findOneOrFail(blacklisted_id);
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(404).send({error: error});
  }
  let blacklist = new Blacklist();
  blacklist.user = blacklistedUser;
  // user.blacklists.push(blacklist);

  try {
    await blacklistRepository.save(blacklist);
    await userRepository.save(user);
    res.status(201).send('success blacklisted');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).send({error: error});
  }
}
```

It works for the blacklist, I have a new blacklist with the id of the blacklisted user. But I cannot add a user_blacklist (hope I'm clear)

So I tryed to add:

```
user.blacklists.push(blacklist); // see above comment
```

But I get

> (node:40495) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

### Actual:

```
blacklist // works
+------------+--------------+
| id         | userId       |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 1            |
+------------+--------------+
user_blacklist // not works cause of cannot push and save
+------------+--------------+
| userId     | blacklistId  |
+------------+--------------+
| Empty                     |
+------------+--------------+
```

### Expected: (so user #2 is blacklisted from user #1)

```
blacklist
+------------+--------------+
| id         | userId       |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 2            |
+------------+--------------+
user_blacklist
+------------+--------------+
| userId     | blacklistId  |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 1            | 
+------------+--------------+
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
user.blacklists = [blacklist];
```

and then save the user Entity.

For more info take a look here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md

Comment: This is working, thanks very much. But there is a problem, this delete the previous blacklisted users. Example: user #1 blacklist user #2 it's ok, but if after he blacklist user#3 then user3 will be in the database blacklist but the 2 has been delete.. That why I wanted to push instead init with new array, any idea?

Comment: Oh I see, so, you need to recover the user with the blacklist relation, so then you will be able to push to the list of blacklisted users you already have.                  For example  return await this.getUserRepository().findOne({
      relations: ["blacklists"],
      where: { userId: userId }
    });

Comment: Wtffff it's working, when I console.log(user) the blacklists[] property contain each blacklist BUT in the database I have only one record. How this is possible?

Comment: Euh the blacklist I get is all the duplicate my bad, same thing :( Btw You know how can I delete blacklist table and replace blacklist_id by blacklister_user ? user manytomany user ?

Comment: In the @JoinTable you can specify the joinColumn and inverseJoinColumn. Ex : @ManyToMany(type => Blacklist)
@JoinTable({
  name: "user_blacklist", joinColumn: { name: "user_id" },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: "blacklister_user" }
})

Comment: I mean I want to delete Blacklist entity, and just have user, user_blacklisted tables (without any blacklist entity) with user_id and user_blacklisted_id so I can just take all the row with user_id = x to get each blacklisted user without this blacklist entity, or it's bad practice, idk what do You think about ?

Comment: hmm, I think you will need to create a new entity anyways and map the two user entities there with a manyToOne relation. Also typeorm is going to require a primary column, you can use primary: true in the ManyToOne mapping, like @ManyToOne(type => User, { primary: true, nullable: false })@JoinColumn({ name: "user_id" }).

Comment: Ok thanks, btw in still doesn't persist in user_blacklist :(. when I console.log(user) before save, I see the blacklist property with the blacklisted user but it's not persisting